# TypeError: value.forEach is not a function at FormArray.patchValue

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
TypeError: value.forEach is not a function
    at FormArray.patchValue.
```

I am getting data from Laravel and I want these data to display in a FormArray.

My code looks like this:

```js
this.http.get("http://data_dink" + '/' + event.value)
 .toPromise().then(data => 
 {
    console.log(data);
    this.getSelectedServiceData = data;
    console.log(this.getSelectedServiceData.service);
    this.addForm.get('services').patchValue(this.getSelectedServiceData.service);
 });
```

`data` variable (response from get request) has such object:

```
{
   "msg":"Service Information",
   "service":{
      "id":1,
      "name":"Web Development",
      "description":"Test per web development",
      "price":"200.00",
      "created_at":"2020-05-04T03:07:28.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-05-06T03:07:28.000000Z",
      "view_service":{
         "href":"api\/v1\/service\/1",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   }
}
```

FormArray built from this object:

```
{
   "msg":"List of all services",
   "services":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Web Development",
         "description":"Test per web development",
         "price":"200.00",
         "created_at":"2020-05-04T03:07:28.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2020-05-06T03:07:28.000000Z"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Java",
         "description":"test per java",
         "price":"100.00",
         "created_at":"2020-05-20T03:07:57.000000Z",
         "updated_at":"2020-05-20T03:07:57.000000Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: actually my data comes like this: {"msg":"Service Information","service":{"id":1,"name":"Web Development","description":"Test per web development","price":"200.00","created_at":"2020-05-04T03:07:28.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-05-06T03:07:28.000000Z","view_service":{"href":"api\/v1\/service\/1","method":"GET"}}}

Comment: Since You don't have services field in Your response object (cause You get an item) and it's `service`, I assume that You want to do this: `this.addForm.get('service')` without `patchValue` statement since You're already telling api to get an item of service.

Comment: @num8er, look at my first comment, the data comes like that.

Comment: then can You add to answer what is `console.log( this.addForm.get('services') )` ?

Comment: FormArray {validator: null, asyncValidator: null, pristine: false, touched: true, _onCollectionChange: ƒ, …}
asyncValidator: null
controls: [FormGroup]
errors: null
pristine: false
status: "INVALID"
statusChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
touched: true
validator: null
value: [{…}]
valueChanges: EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …} ...

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [manual for FormArray patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#patchValue) it accepts array as first argument:

```js
patchValue(
  value:        any[], 
  options: { 
    onlySelf?:  boolean; 
    emitEvent?: boolean; 
  } = {}
): void
```

and also error informs that it tries to use `value` argument as an array, I assume that argument  for `patchValue` should be wrapped inside `[]`

so solution to Your question should be:

```js
this.addForm
      .get('services')
      .patchValue(
        [
          this.getSelectedServiceData.service
        ]
      )
```